# Wave function in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, wave-particle-duality

I was wondering about something while studying quantum mechanics. If the wave function collapses when measuring a particle and assumes a single position, how do we know that it was a wave in the first place?

P.S.: sorry if it is absurdly simple, I was just confused and couldn't come up with any explanation.

Comment: The "collapse of the wave function" is nothing but a colorful expression for the Born rule. It doesn't have an objective counterpart (like the little implosion that people seem to be implying when they hear the term). That the wave function is a field is simply given by its mathematical definition. The field has some values before the measurement and some other values thereafter. That's all.

Comment: Doesn't the collapse of a wave function mean it takes a definite position due to the act of measurement. So doesn't that mean that every time we measure the particle it takes a definite position so how do we know it was acting like a wave (according to the schrodingers equation )in the first place? - I'm confused

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that, at all. There is nothing that could take a definite position, to begin with. There are no little balls in there! The position that your detector shows you are three NUMBERS x, y, z. Absolutely nothing special is taking place at the coordinates x, y, z. The Born rule merely tells you that the next measurement that you make will behave AS IF the system had been given a fresh start at those coordinates. It would not only take an infinite amount of energy to actually localize the system at that point, there would also be an infinity of newly created particles coming out.

Comment: @MatthewV There's a nice discussion on this provided by ACuriousMind on his blog, check it out [here](https://gaugingthoughts.wordpress.com/2014/12/01/no-more-waves-or-why-the-idea-of-wavefunctions-needs-to-die/)!

Comment: @MatthewV: I disagree with the Curious Mind. I am a materialist, and I think that everything around us is MATTER. So, the w.f. is the description of the MATTER behavior. And this is not a so bad description, the QM is excellent description of the microscopic world. This is what gives us some confidence that the w.f. is quite a close description of what **really** we have in our apparatuses. That the w.f. doesn't answer to all our questions, well, we have to do more investigations.

Comment: In most cases the "wavelike" behavior can only be seen by repeating the experiment many time to accumulate a statistical pattern--try watching [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfPeprQ7oGc) for a simple cartoon introduction to the [double slit experiment](http://www.upscale.utoronto.ca/PVB/Harrison/DoubleSlit/DoubleSlit.html) which is a good example of this (each electron is only measured to hit a discrete point on the screen, but the statistical pattern built up by many electrons is a wavelike double-slit interference pattern).

Comment: I agree with ACuriousOne's idea that the wave function is not so useful an idea. I advocate for the Heisenberg picture as much as possible because it's easier to understand, closer to classical mechanics, and a lot easier to use for calculation. That said, I don't understand the actual points ACuriousMind is trying to make in his blog post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It was not a wave.**

The wavefunction is not a wave. It fulfills the Schrödinger equation in the position representation, and although that looks similar to what one usually writes as "wave equation", and produces similar interference phenomena, it is *not a wave in any physical sense*. The wave function *is not a physical object*, it is merely a way of writing the coefficients for a quantum state in the position basis. It is not measureable, and there is, in general, no physical quantity oscillating that would be associated with it.

Any object in quantum mechanics is described by an abstract state in a [Hilbert space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space3), and the abstract [Schrödinger equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) tells you that there is a basis of "stationary states" that evolve in time just by being multiplied by a phase $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}Et}$, i.e. essentially doing nothing. If you now add several of these states with different energies/Hamiltonian eigenvalues $E$, the overall time evolution of the state is *not* a simple multiplication anymore, and the state is indeed changing. Essentially, this is all "interference" means - you have phases $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}Et}$ with different $E$ that can be added, and then some non-trivial kind of evolution appears. (Since usual solutions to wave equation also contain $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\omega t}$ in this  way, this explains the name)

But that doesn't mean quantum states are waves. It also doesn't mean they are particles. They are quantum objects, states in a Hilbert space. Not *waves*. Not *particles*. When we look at them in some ways, e.g. at their time evolutions, and their properties of superposition and interference, they look like our inutitive notion of waves. When we look at them in detectors, they often look like our intuitive notion of particles.<sup>1</sup> They are **neither**.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>It should be noted that trying to describe that actual occurence of such measurements is still a topic of some debate. Nevertheless, "collapse" is **not** a necessary interpretation of the math - [decoherence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence) approaches to measurements/emergence of classical physics do not need that concept.</sup>

Comment: We don't know what is the wave-function (w.f.). But we have some confirmation that it describes quite well the **reality** that passes through our apparatuses. That's why the closest image that we can make to ourselves about that reality, is **wave**. The confirmation is that besides predicting well probabilities of measurements, all the intermediate steps before the detector (passing through fields, beam-splitters, etc.) are well-described with the concept of a complex wave possessing magnitude and phase (concept already known to us from e.m. waves).

Comment: @Sofia: While it is *possible* to describe most of quantum mechanics in terms of wave functions, it is not the most advisable way: It doesn't generalize easily to QFT, it is difficult to explain what spin, angular momentum and the like are, and it lures people into thinking of quantum objects as classical waves. I can write down Hamiltonians where the solution to the Schrödinger equation is *far* from being any kind of wave. I can consider systems with finitely many degrees of freedom that will not be described by such a function on the reals at all.

Comment: This answer boils my experimentalist blood. In what sense are electromagnetic waves more of a "physical object" than a quantum wave function? They're both mathematical book-keeping tricks to reliably reproduce what we see in experiments. They're just useful constructs in our mental metaphor of Nature.

Comment: I agree with DanielSank as well--all of physics is basically just making mathematical models which are used to predict experimental results, the statement that some element of a model is less of a "physical object" than any other element of a model seems "not even wrong" unless you provide some precise definition of the term "physical object" (I'm not aware of there being any existing commonly-accepted definition among physicists).

Comment: @ACuriousMind: of course there are cases in which the wave-functions looks rather like a particle, not as a wave. I can't know what examples you have in mind, but I have in mind localized wave-packets. But even these wave-packets undergo a splitting at a beam-splitter, and produce interference if and then and where they cross simultaneously the path of one another.

Comment: @ACuriousMind (cont.) But there is something else to consider when one judges a given problem. I won't use QFT instead of QM because, as you say, there are cases where ... For a specific problem I use the best language for that given problem.

Comment: @Hypnosifl : Hi! At least when judging quantum objects, one should make a difference between the quantum object that travels through our apparatus, and the mathematical description. With classical objects we don't need that, a piece of chalk, even a tiny pebble, we can observe without disturbing. But not with the quantum objects. So, what is there in the apparatus we don't know. We really can only construct just a model and hope that it will work. So is the wave-function. Though, what I told to Curious Mind is that we treat a given problem with the formalism, QFT or QM, which is best for it.

Comment: @Sofia - What do you mean by "quantum object" distinct from "the mathematical description"? Does a term like "electron" have any well-defined meaning outside of the context of mathematical models involving electrons in QM? And I don't understand what the question of whether we can "observe without disturbing" has to do with the issue of whether physics can ever tell us anything more about "reality" than the best mathematical models for predicting readings on our instruments.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: That electron that produces the fringes, what it is in fact? A wave? A particle (like the piece of chalk)? Could it be that we have "full" and "empty" waves? (I.e. in the 2slit exp. through one slit passes a wave carrying an electron and through the other an empty wave?) Or, what we have is some "deformation of the space-time? (somebody proposed such a thing). The wave-function we know, we calculate it, and is the best description we can infer about the behavior of what we have in the apparatus, but we cannot claim that it's a perfect description, because we don't know.

Comment: @Sofia - I would say that physics doesn't tell us what *anything* "is in fact", independent of models--that's a philosophical question. It's true that we might have future models that are more accurate than current ones, and they might model the electrons somewhat differently, just as general relativity replaced the Newtonian concept of gravity as an instantaneous force with the notion of matter/energy curving spacetime. But it's still just a matter of one mathematical model supplanting another, you can never have any basis in physics for talking about any "reality" separate from such models.

Comment: @DanielSank: EM fields/waves are *physical* in the sense that charges move in them (that's how we *define* an EM field, after all - by its action on test charges). There's no such interpretation for the "wavefunction" - it has no such test objects, instead it encodes a probability distribution that is equivalently encoded in many other things as well, while we'd be hard pressed to find such equivalent formulations for EM fields.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: When you say those probability distributions are encoded in other things, you're going to have to be explicit or I will assume you're talking out the proverbial "rear end". Furthermore, whatever those other "things" are, if they encode the probability distribution in a quantum experiment they are by _definition_ the wave function by the same reasoning that the "thing" which tells me how the charges move is by definition the E&M field.

Comment: @DanielSank: The wavefunction is just the expansion coefficients in the position basis. Choose any other complete basis of the abstract Hilbert space (e.g. momentum), and their coefficients also encode the same information. Also, you could switch to the density matrix formalism. And, again, in systems with finitely many degrees of freedom - e.g. only spin - there's no such wavefunction (as in "function on the reals telling us what's gonna happen") at all. To pick one of these descriptions and say "That's what it really is" is giving ontological weight to it that is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

This is a supplement to my original answer. For rigor, we have to make a distinction between the **reality** that travels in our apparatuses, and the mathematical description that we give it. However, the mathematical description proved to be **so successful**, that sometimes we place a sign of equality between them. 
About what happens with a quantum object when it interacts with a macroscopic apparatus, we **don't know**. At present, we don't have a better tool to handle this problem than the collapse (reduction postulate of von Neumann). And we simply use it because we have to go on, to work.

Now, the wave-form for the wave-function works well in some cases, and works badly in other cases. But in most of the cases in which interference in involves, it works well.
For instance if we put on the way of the particle a beam-splitter, we **believe** that we get a splitting of the wave, into a reflected wave and a transmitted wave. I.e. although we speak of one particle, we believe that we get two waves. Then, if we redirect, with mirrors, the two waves to cross the path of one another, we get an interference pattern (see experiments with the Mach-Zender interferometer in Wikipedia) if in the crossing region we place a photographic plate.

However, the interference tableau doesn't appear for one single particle. We have to prepare many particles carefully, in an identical way, i.e. same type of particle, same velocity, etc.

So, interference pattern is produced by waves, while a single particle is detected on the photographic plate in a single place, as any particle.

Though, we incline to admit that before the detection on the plate, we had for each particle and particle, the two waves as I said above, and at the detection all the energy of the particle is delivered to one single molecule on the plate.

(The process of impressing the photographic plate is some more complicated but I restricted myself to a simple line. What is most important is that at the detection on the plate, the particle doesn't impart its energy to all the region covered by the interference pattern. No, the energy is delivered to a single point (e.g. a certain molecule is decomposed) ).

Comment: The wave function is a field. If it describes the system perfectly well, it's as good as any other description that gives the right answers. Are you happier with matrices? Mathematically matrix mechanics is equivalent and predicts the same outcome. Is that a better physical picture?

Comment: I am back! But you have to tell me what you have in mind behind the statement that the w.f. is a field. Let me say frankly - to understand what is the w.f. is worthy a Nobel prize. But nobody knows. We can't say what was in the apparatus before we measure, because these tiny objects don't allow us to measure them without decohering them. Whatever we can say of the w.f. is that it is a good machine to predict probabilities. Thus, field, or wave, what does it matter?

Comment: To understand what is the w.f. we need, maybe, apparatuses more delicate than these particles. But, probably, this is a NO-GO.